# Redirect all URLs that BEGIN with index.php to / while also redirecting http->https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Old URLs look like:

```
http://example.com/index.php/whatever/page

or

http://www.example.com/some-url-that-doesnt-begin-with-index/
```

New urls would be:

```
https://example.com/index.php/whatever/page

or

https://example.com/some-url-that-doesnt-begin-with-index/
```

Which is to say that the old URLs currently:

1. may or may not include www
2. are all http
3. most of them have index.php right after the domain and before the rest of the URL, but not all
   of them.

I'm just looking for the .htaccess rules to accomplish this that doesn't implement several redirects.

Comment: How did you get on with the below answer, S16?

Answer (score -1):

To redirect http requests to https  ,You can use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ 
RewriteRule . https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```